# Parameters of methods available only to logged in users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Some methods for the controller, such as deleting messages, are only available to logged-in users. In the controller, I call the method to delete messages

```
this.messagePersistenceService.deleteMessageSent(id, this.authorizationService.getUserId());
```

https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/src/main/java/com/web/web/controller/MessageRestController.java#L142

I transfer the ID (obtained from authorizationService) parameter of the logged in user to the method.

https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/core/jpa/service/MessagePersistenceServiceImpl.java#L87
In this way I pass the ID of the logged in user to the method.

However, I thought, why not put authorizationService eg in the MessagePersistenceServiceImpl class. And then send only the message ID to the method

```
this.messagePersistenceService.deleteMessageSent(id);
```

and the ID of the logged-in user is only obtained in the method deleteMessageSent.

What do you think about it? The method is available only to the logged-in user. Is the ID parameter of the logged in user to be sent to the method or not, and the identifier can be obtained only in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the ID parameter of the logged in user to be sent to the method or not?

**NOT!!**

The service layer should/cannot not trust the caller. Good security means that service layer must always validate parameters, including whether the active user is allowed to do the operation.

Also remember: The service is commonly caller by a controller, i.e. with values from a UI. Even without ill-intended users, the UI can be stale (two users updating same information), so service must also validate that object being operated on is still in the correct state for that.

If you also do data-level security, the service must also verify that the caller is authorized to delete that particular message, e.g. a user might only be allowed to delete their own messages, so service must validate that `message.userId == activeUserId`, to prevent someone spoofing the UI request to delete random messages.

Comment: So I have to modify the code in order to send only the message ID to the method and then obtain the user ID from my other service this.authorizationService.getUserId() in the messagePersistenceService? So I can't send the ID of the logged in user. This is a mistake?

Comment: It's a potential security flaw, but it depends on how much you trust the caller. As your code evolves, the service method may be called by UI (controller), but also directly via web service, and you cannot trust values from a web service. Or even values from a web browser. They can be spoofed, so a secure app needs to guard against that. Starting with good patterns now will help keep you app safe(r) in the future.